# Form is not submitted on pressing Enter key but submiited onclicking submit button

Tags: forms, submit

This may be silly but i really want to know about this, not only me this may be question a from thousands of students.

The following link is my university website 
[LINK](http://ptuexam.com)

there is a login panel. 
after entering my username & password if i click enter then page reloads but the expected behaviour is to submit the form.
To actually login into this website you need to click on submit button.

Can anyone explain me about this.

- what i think is there must be some onlick event on sumit button but
  the button there is  
   `<input type="submit">` so by default it
  need to submit by pressing enter as usally happens in all websites
- I also noticed one more thing that the form tag is missing there.

Any help or explanation about this question is appreciated

---

**EDIT**
*just enter a wrong email and password*

1. **if u press enter:** there is no red color error message of wrong
   email and password
2. **if u click submit**:there is a red color error message of wrong email and password

Comment: I tried pressing Enter but it did submit the form. What browser were you using? (me Google Chrome) Missing form tag could be the problem.

Comment: i m using chrome. and this problem is in all browsers

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about analysis of an existing site, not a question about a specific javascript issue.

Comment: @Anonymous I see it posts the form data in chrome network console, and failed on login (of course I don't have an account), but it did submit the form.

Comment: this form has an anonymous behaviour. i just want to know about this as a developer's point of view

Comment: @Anonymous The form tag is not missing, you have a big form in the body `<form method="post" action="index.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="form1">` you can check the javascript which submit this form to see any differece between click and press enter. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour is that when input with type `submit` is present in the form, the form will get sumitted upon click on the button, or enter key press when some form control has focus. Since controls on your site are not inside of `form` the expected behaviour will not be seen.

Comment: The entire page is a form, the form tags are adjacent to the body tags, so this isn't the answer.

Comment: @VLAS if the submit button is not inside form tag then the expected behaviour is that nothing happens means form neither submit on click nor by pressiong enter but here the page reloads on pressing enter

Comment: @Anonymous—not at all. There could be a listener on the input elements and the button. But that is moot, the controls **are** in a form which has a submit listener: `onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();"`. Seeing *javascript:* in an *onsubmit* attribute isn't encouraging.